# How can I include a string variable in my XPath in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, xpath

I have a function that parses an xml file using XPath and returns the results in a html table. I want to amend my XPath to include another string variable but can't get it to work.

I've tried various combination of +s and "" but can't seem to get it working, what's more, even replacing the single quotes in the path variable with double quotes breaks the function.

```
// doesnt work with IE!!
function showResult(xml) {

var txt = ""; //string for result

var lu_ID = "940gzzlu";

var path = '/svg/g[@id="interchange-circles"]/g[contains(@id,"940gzzlu")]/g/path[@class="blue-fill"]/@d | /svg/g[@id="interchange-circles"]/g[contains(@id,"940gzzlu")]/g/path[@class="blue-fill"]/../../@id'; 

    if (xml.evaluate) {

        var nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null); //select first path and pass result to nodes
        var result = nodes.iterateNext();

        while (result) {
            //check if first letter is M so know its the coordinate
            var crrPath = result.nodeValue;
            if(crrPath.substring(0,1)=="M"){
                txt += "<td>" + result.nodeValue + "</td>";
            } else {
                txt += "<tr><td>" + result.nodeValue + "</td>";
            }
            result = nodes.iterateNext();
        } 

    }

    document.getElementById("stationlist").innerHTML = txt;

//alert(txt);
}
```

I want to add the lu_ID variable to the path variable and return the same result. At the moment, even replacing the single quotes from the path variable breaks the code.
I'm new to JavaScript but have googled and it tells me double and single quotes are the same thing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below approach.

```
var path = "/svg/g[@id='interchange-circles']/g[contains(@id,'"+lu_ID +"')]/g/path[@class='blue-fill']/@d | /svg/g[@id='interchange-circles']/g[contains(@id,'"+lu_ID +"')]/g/path[@class='blue-fill']/../../@id";
```

Comment: Hi thank you - that worked. Could I ask why there's no single quote at the start and end of the string please?

Comment: it's ok I geddit now - the single quotes are for to enclose the variable. i think it some instances of my code i dont have a var before path, just path=, which could be confusing things.